# Who can modify the micro-code of instructions in Intel SGX?

Tags: intel-sgx

I've read [this article about Intel SGX](https://blog.quarkslab.com/overview-of-intel-sgx-part-1-sgx-internals.html)

Under **Instructions**, it says

> All these instructions are implemented in micro-code (so that their behavior can be modified)

Are users able to modify the micro-code of Intel SGX instructions, or is this something that only Intel can do?"

Comment: This seems off-topic for me.
I recommend migration to StackOverflow or another SE site

Comment: Intel microcode updates are signed although the actual encoding is uncertain. Not likely that you can load your own version.